# Class 'Mobile_Detect' not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

first of all my code works correctly
then I finish another task and I push
then make a pull  and resolve conflicts 
after that I intercepted this error [error messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKL9l.png)

this is my composer.json code

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.23",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "^2.1",
    "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "^2.2",
    "bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php": "~2.0.0",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
},
```

this is my controller

```
use Mobile_Detect;

trait WithMeetingTrait

{

protected function getMeetingId($model)
{
    /**
     * @var $model Seminar
     */
    return mb_strtoupper(substr($model::className(), 0, 3)) . '-' . $model->id;
}

protected function allowedToCreate()
{
    // TRUE if super admin or $this->userIsModelOwner();
}

/**
 * @param $link
 * @return mixed
 * @throws InvalidConfigException
 * @throws NotInstantiableException
 */
public function actionStart($link)
{
    /**
     * @var $model Seminar
     */
    $model = $this->findModelByColumn('link', $link);

    // TODO only super admin or the room teacher can create the room if allowedToCreate()
    $meeting  = $this->getWebConference();
    $response = $meeting->create(
        $this->getMeetingId($model),
        $model->name,
        Url::to(['seminar/join', 'link' => $model->link], true),
        ['ownerType' => $model::className(), 'ownerId' => $model->id]
    );

    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    $settings = Settings::find()->where(['setting_name' => Settings::DEVICE_TYPE])->one();
    if ($settings->value === 'Yes') {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) {
            $icon = ' ⬛';
        } elseif ($detect->isTablet()) {
            $icon = ' ';
        } else {
            $icon = ' ';
        }
    } else {
        $icon = '';
    }
```

I use this service from packagist [mobile detect](https://packagist.org/packages/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib)

I need help please

Answer (score 1):

Check the namespace of the mobile detect script.
I can include the script with

```
use Detection\MobileDetect;
$mobileDetect = new MobileDetect();
```

Comment: Is your vendor directory maybe added to .gitignore? and is mobiledetect in your vendor directory?

Comment: Then that is probbely your problem, run composer again to install it

Comment: the problem is still the same

Comment: Did you do composer install then or composer update? after that it should be installed in your vendor directory.

Comment: I just tried it with a fresh Yii2 install - it definitely works with `use Mobile_Detect`- when the class cannot be found, it has to be a problem with the install or composers autoloader - can you check if this file is present: `vendors/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib/Mobile_Detect.php`?

Comment: The file is in my vendor directory. Probably something is going wrong with the autoload of your composer on that file. When you take a look at the mobile detect page I see also they made an extencion for yii2 framework, have you tried that?
https://github.com/alexandernst/yii2-device-detect/

Comment: The first time the same code was running correctly but after the push I do a pull from another branch and the mobile detect file in vendor was deleted

Answer (score 1):

I got that error when do composer update version. The reason is big changing in namespace. So, you can use old version, or change the namespace:
[image]

Check origin reference [here](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/).